# How to Maintain Button State in UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, uicollectionviewcell

I am using a UICollectionView and I have set a class for its cells.
In the cell I have an image and a Like Button that when tapped it changes state (changes Button image). Note: my collectionView is shown horizontally and covers the entire screen.

**My Problem:** The cells are reusing and the like Buttons state is changed for every two cells. If I like image1 then image3, image5 and also change the Like Button. and if I like image2 then image4, image6 and so on change their state.

I know this has to do with the reusing of cells. My question is how do I fix it so that each button is either unique or the state of the button is set to unselected in each cell.
I have found similar question involving a UITableView but the answers don't seem to help me. So hopefully I'll find an answer here.

**My code:**
Note: This is a DetailView so the data has been passed as a PFObject (Im using Parse.com Backend)

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {

return 1;

}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return 10;

}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
VestimentaDetailCell *cell = (VestimentaDetailCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.imageFile.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LoadLook.png"];

PFFile *storeLooks = [self.vestimenta objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%ld", (long)indexPath.item]];

[storeLooks getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (!error && data.length > 0) {

        cell.imageFile.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    } else {

        NSLog(@"No image found");

    }

return cell;
}
```

**VestimentaDetailCell.m**

The Like Button has its action:

```
- (IBAction)likeLook:(id)sender {

    if ([sender isSelected]) {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Like.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setSelected:NO];


    } else {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Liked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [sender setSelected:YES];

        UIImageView *like = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 220, 100, 100)];
        like.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Love.png"];
        [self addSubview:like];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{like.alpha = 0.0;}];

        NSLog(@"Liked Image");

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Track the state of the buttons by linking it to your datasource or a datastructure that maps indexes to selected state (NSMutableDictionary or NSMutatbleArray possibly).

**The below is just a suggestion, this problem has a few approaches, mainly based on the style you develop.**

Example 1:
Add a state field to whatever objects are in your dataSource (may make your object class messy)

Example 2:
If using a dictionary, the key is the cell index, the value can be empty. if the button is selected then place it in the dictionary, if not then don't. That way the lookup is fast, and you know quickly if it is selected or not.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
VestimentaDetailCell *cell = (VestimentaDetailCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.imageFile.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LoadLook.png"];

PFFile *storeLooks = [self.vestimenta objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%ld", (long)indexPath.item]];

//============================================ Modified
BOOL selected = [self isCellPathSelected:indexPath.row];
// if selected, show in the UI, otherwise revert to not selected
//============================================ Modified


[storeLooks getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (!error && data.length > 0) {

        cell.imageFile.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    } else {

        NSLog(@"No image found");

    }

return cell;
}

//============================================ Modified
- (BOOL) isCellPathSelected:(int)index{
   //look in the dictionary, if there, return yes, otherwise return no
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such explicit answer! I think I'm almost there. Since I am new to developing I do have to ask for your help again. Could you help me construct the dictionary?

Comment: I can't figure out how to get this done, could you help please?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that VestimentaDetailCell is a subclass of UICollectionViewCell.

Create a property of your button in the .h file.

In this class if you override this method:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
      [super prepareForReuse];
      [yourbuttonproperty setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Like.png"]
                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [yourbuttonproperty setSelected:NO];
}
```

This is usually used to clean up code and as per the apple docs definition [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionReusableView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionReusableView/prepareForReuse), it states:

> When a view is dequeued for use, this method is called before the
>   corresponding dequeue method returns the view to your code. Subclasses
>   can override this method and use it to reset properties to their
>   default values and generally make the view ready to use again. You
>   should not use this method to assign any new data to the view. That is
>   the responsibility of your data source object.

Maybe what I implemented in the function might not be as per your requirements but I think this is what you need to play around with.

This will reset the button state and not give the pressed button state. So this will mean all your buttons will be in the normal state.

I then think you need to also have a delegate method for your like button which is implemented by your view controller. In this delegate method, all you do is populate the dictionary or array for any cells that has been tapped following the method William mentions.